# Push new values to array while keeping old one intact

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

Not sure how to explain this or search for an answer in that matter.

I am creating a form to send and would like to use an existing array and push it to a new one without affecting the old one.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
$required_fields = array( "full_name", "email", "phone", "preferred_date" );
$whitelist = array_push( $required_fields, "patient_type", "appointment_time", "comments");
```

But it changes the $required fields array when doing it this way. How can I push those existing values into the $whitelist array without affecting the $required_fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

If you take a look at the documentation of array_push it actually modifies the first parameter and only returns the number of new elements in the array.

What you're trying to do is make a copy of the required_fields array and then add some new elements. You can use the array_merge function to get this done.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Oops I get so wrapped up in stuff sometimes I forget about these functions. Thanks good sir!

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want `array_merge`:

```
$whitelist = array_merge( $required_fields, array(
  "patient_type", 
  "appointment_time", 
  "comments"
));
```

This will leave `$required_fields` alone and `$whitelist` will be:

```
array(
  "full_name", 
  "email", 
  "phone", 
  "preferred_date", 
  "patient_type", 
  "appointment_time", 
  "comments"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge). Please, note that `array_merge` only accepts parameters of type `array`.

Instead, when you use `array_push` the first parameter will itself get modified. If you look at the documentation for [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), the first parameter is passed by reference, and gets modified itself, which is why in your case `$required_fields` is being modified.

Correct code, therefore, should be:

```
$required_fields = array( "full_name", "email", "phone", "preferred_date" );
$whitelist = array_merge( $required_fields, array("patient_type", "appointment_time",  "comments"));
```